# How do i grep for this pattern

Tags: regex, unix, awk, grep

I have a file which has multiple lines of this pattern

```
20140604 02:05:51:142 INFO  M2F_F2M_Server - Number of messages in the Input Queue : "ANCDGBBBB" Count : 0
20140604 02:07:58:145 INFO  M2F_F2M_Server - Number of messages in the Input Queue : "ANCDGBBBB" Count : 8
```

I want to only grep for "20140604" date and as well as where count !=0

I tried the following command

```
grep '20140604' | grep -v 'Count : 0' XYZ.dat .  But with no use.
```

Please help

Please note there can be other date entries also in the file like '20140607' but my concern is only of 20140604.

My sample output should only have :

```
20140604 02:07:58:145 INFO  M2F_F2M_Server - Number of messages in the Input Queue : "ANCDGBBBB" Count : 8
```

Comment: grep '20140604' XYZ.dat | grep -v 'Count : 0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to pass the filename `XYZ.dat` to your first grep command. If you pass it, it should work. However, you can do the job with just a single grep command. Like this:

```
grep '^20140604.*Count : [^0].*$' XYZ.dat
```

Comment: Hi i want lines where count is not zero and of '20140604' date

Comment: Hi hek2mgl Thanks :) but im getting the lines where COUNT : 0, i want lines where COUNT is not zero for ex: COUNT :9.

Comment: Ok, edited again. `grep` is the way to go then. Have remove `sed` and `awk` solutions. I have only used them because I didn't got the question at  the first attempt.

Answer (score 3):

An awk solution:

```
awk '$1==20140604 && $NF{print}' file
```

`$1` is the first word and `$NF` (corresponding to `count`).